# Custom contrasts in R (similar to 'special' contrasts in SPSS)

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I often use the `ezANOVA` package (or `afex`) to conduct repeated measures ANOVAs - I was taught how to run custom contrasts in SPSS, but cannot find a simple solution in R.

Here is an example:

```
require(plyr) 
require(ez)
require(afex)

data(ANT)

#Aggregate
x<-ddply(ANT, .(subnum, cue, block), summarise, rt=mean(rt))
x$block<-factor(x$block)

#Anova
ezANOVA(x
        ,dv=rt
        ,wid=subnum
        ,within=.(cue, block)
        ,type=3
        ,detailed=T)

#Alternative Anova Method
a<-ez.glm("subnum","rt",x, within=c("cue","block"), type=3, return="Anova")
nice.anova(a, correction = c("none"))
```

This returns the ANOVA. What I would like to do is run manual contrasts on the data. For example, for cue type, is cue B different to cue C & D (0, -1, .5, .5)?

Comment: Is `ANT` in a specific package? When I run `data(ANT)`, I get `Warning message: In data(ANT) : data set ‘ANT’ not found`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake @gung - its in ez, reordered now.

Comment: Not sure it fully applies to your problem but `?contrasts` might put you on the right track

Comment: Thanks @DominicComtois - I've had a look at the contrasts function, but ezAnova or ez.glm doesn't seem to process them.

Comment: Ok just throwing out a few ideas... maybe try to find an anova function that does make use of `contrasts`; otherwise maybe look into `model.matrix`; maybe consider writing to the package(s) author(s) if you don't get anywhere with the other options.